# How to assemble a contract’s code?

Tags: contract-development, evm

I wrote a contract into bare assembly (no solidity or Vhyper syntax and with all address being static).

How to convert it into bytecode? If possible using the new http://remix.ethereum.org or another web service where nothing has to be compiled.

Comment: No difference from a contract written in any other language. Run `solc --bin --abi --optimize --optimize-runs=200 --output-dir=YourArtifactsFolder YourContractFileName`.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the Solidity compiler only accepts Solidity code as input.

Comment: @smarx Like in  C Solidity has an assembler directive where you can write assembly. But in such directive, you still need to use solidity variables and you can’t be sure of the address of the instructions.

Comment: @goodvibration do you know an online service for it?

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, I'm aware that Solidity allows inline assembly, but you specifically said you _weren't_ using Solidity.

Comment: If you want to compile Solidity in the browser, Remix can do that: http://remix.ethereum.org/.

Comment: @smarc so it does accept assembler, but not true assembler. No I want to assembler in the browser without solidity code.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @mafrasi2's answer, `geth` ships with a binary called `evm`. `evm compile <filename>` can compile "easm" source. You haven't said what sort of assembly you were writing (or given a sample), so I'm not sure if that meets your needs.

Comment: Do you know really no web services for that? Or a precompiled binary?

Comment: You can download geth here: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this assembler](https://github.com/ITSecLabs/EVM-Assembler) in the past, but it's unmaintained and you would need to update it yourself if you want to use any constantinople instructions. I didn't test it, but [this one](https://github.com/fergarrui/evm-assembler) appears to be up to date and a bit more mature. You will have to do some simple preprocessing beforehand, though.